# Arrange values read from an input file into predefined spaces/blocks

Tags: java, java-io

I am reading from a text file with data in a format like name hyphen value e.g. `John - 0.75`. The value is square feet and I want to allocate them into spaces. I have four predefined spaces i.e. space1, space2, space3 and space4. space1 and space2 are 4 square feet total. space3 and space4 are 5 square feet total.

The incoming value can also a value called spacer which represents 1/6 square feet. So Ideally those probably go into space3 and space4. The solution i am trying to develop  should be for different input types. Here's what have so far.

```
public class SpaceAllocator {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double space1= 4.0;
        double space2 = 4.0;
        double space3= 5.0;
        double space4 = 5.0;

        BufferedReader buffReader = null;   

        try {

            buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("input.txt")));
            String line = null;
            String name = null;
            double sqrFeet = 0.0;           
            double space1Counter = 0.0;
            double space2Counter = 0.0;
            double space3Counter = 0.0;
            double space4Counter = 0.0;

            double sqrFeetSum = 0.0;

            while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null){

                String[] tempArr = line.replace("'", "").split("-");

                name = (tempArr[0]!=null)?tempArr[0].trim():"";



                if(tempArr[1]!=null && "spacer".equalsIgnoreCase(tempArr[1].trim())){

                    sqrFeet = 0.166;
                } else {
                    sqrFeet = Double.parseDouble( (tempArr[1]!=null)?tempArr[1].trim():"0");
                }


                sqrFeetSum +=sqrFeet;

                if(sqrFeetSum <space1 && space1Counter<space1 ){
                    space1Counter++;
                } else  if( sqrFeetSum ==  space1 ){
                    sqrFeetSum =0.0;
                    space1=0.0;
                } else  if( sqrFeetSum <space2 && space2Counter<space2){
                    space2Counter++;
                } else  if(sqrFeetSum == space2){
                    sqrFeetSum =0;
                    space2=0;
                } else  if( sqrFeetSum <space3 && space3Counter<space4){
                    space3Counter++;
                } else  if(sqrFeetSum == space3){
                    sqrFeetSum =0;
                    space3 =0.0;
                } else  if( sqrFeetSum <space4 && space4Counter<space4){
                    space4Counter++;
                } else  if(sqrFeetSum == space4){
                    sqrFeetSum =0;
                    space4=0.0;
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {          
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        try {
            buffReader.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {              

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is the example input file i have.

```
    John - 1
    Lucy - .5 
    Jack - .75
    Adam - .75
    Nancy - .75
    Jason - 'spacer'
    Joe - 1
    Molly - .75
    Kindell - .5
    Jose - .5
    Madison - .75
    David - 1
    Harry - 1
    Norman - .75
    Ortez - .5
    Patrick - .5
    Jackie - 1
    Laura - .5
    Randy - .5
```

and output something like this, not exactly,

```
space 1
John
Jack
....

space 2
Smith
Lucy
...

space 3
Ortez
....


space 4
Jackie
....
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I am trying to allocate the values/users, but can't seem to do it properly.

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Other than not exceeding the size of each "space", are there any other constraints?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it is. Just allocate them into predefined spaces and there's no other constraint other than no exceeding the size of predefined spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. You need a "sum" counter for each space.
2. You need a list of names assigned to each space.
3. Consider breaking this into smaller methods that each perform a well-defined task. For example, you might want one method which reads the entire file into memory, another method which assigns a person to a space, and another method that prints the output. Breaking up a complex task into smaller pieces helps you focus on each piece individually.
4. You might want to create a `Space` class which has an `add()` method to add a person to that space. This class will encapsulate the sum and list of names suggested in 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am stuck at assignment part. For names assosicated with spaces i think i need a HashMap<Integer,String[]> hm = new HashMap<Integer,String[]>(); for printing part.